# Incorrect syntax near ')' in SQL Server SCALAR FUNCTION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have created a scalar function in SQL server. I am not able to locate the syntax error. Secondly, I have created the function to check for the condition. I would like to know if the format is correct. Please help me

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SetRateCalculation]
    (
        @FromDate Datetime,
        @ToDate Datetime
    )
    RETURNS MONEY
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- Declare the return variable here
        RETURN (SELECT CASE WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%GAMMAPLEX%' THEN '4.00' 
                      WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND `enter code here`CPTDescription LIKE '%OCTAGAM%' THEN '38.25'
                      WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE'%CARIMUNE%' THEN '26.00'
                      WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%PRIVIGEN%' THEN '39.98'
                      WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%GAMUNEX%' THEN '39.98'
                      WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%GAMMAGARD%' THEN '43.00'
                      WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE'%BIVIGAM%' THEN '38.25'
                      )

    END
    GO
```

Comment: what error are you getting and which database are you using?

Comment: the final `END` is missing: `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END`. Whatever `ServiceDate` refers to

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @GarimaGupta: it's right in the title (and the question): "SQL Server"

Comment: Thank you all, it worked with END

Comment: I would turn this into an inline table valued function. The syntax is nearly identical in this case but it will be a LOT more flexible (and performant). But your code is incomplete. This references columns ServiceDate and CPTDescription but there is no table in your query.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SetRateCalculation]
(
    @FromDate Datetime,
    @ToDate Datetime
)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    RETURN (SELECT CASE WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%GAMMAPLEX%' THEN '4.00' 
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND `enter code here`CPTDescription LIKE '%OCTAGAM%' THEN '38.25'
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE'%CARIMUNE%' THEN '26.00'
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%PRIVIGEN%' THEN '39.98'
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%GAMUNEX%' THEN '39.98'
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%GAMMAGARD%' THEN '43.00'
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE'%BIVIGAM%' THEN '38.25'
                END   )

END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to END your CASE (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SetRateCalculation]
(
    @FromDate Datetime,
    @ToDate Datetime
)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    RETURN (SELECT CASE
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%GAMMAPLEX%' THEN '4.00' 
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND `enter code here`CPTDescription LIKE '%OCTAGAM%' THEN '38.25'
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE'%CARIMUNE%' THEN '26.00'
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%PRIVIGEN%' THEN '39.98'
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%GAMUNEX%' THEN '39.98'
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE '%GAMMAGARD%' THEN '43.00'
                  WHEN ServiceDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND CPTDescription LIKE'%BIVIGAM%' THEN '38.25'
               END -- END CASE
                  )

END
GO
```

Comment: Excatly right. You are just missing the "END" prior to the close bracket.